# Error installing MySQLdb driver in python2.7 on mac

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Error while installing the MySQLdb driver in python2.7 on mac

```
Prompt error is：Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

Comment: I want get a Support、thranks.